# Replace all plain text links with href and remove https, https and www

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to replace all plain links with hrefs and remove the beginning part of the url.

The current code I am working with finds https and http links and replaces them, but it doesn't work with www. plain links.

```js
var links = $('#links').text();

var formatText = links.replace(/((http|https|www):\/\/[\w?=&.\/-;#~%-]+(?![\w\s?&.\/;#~%"=-]*>))/g, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a><br>');

$('#links2').html(formatText);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="links">
https://www.example.com/<br>
https://www.example.com/blah/blah/<br>
http://www.example.com/<br>
http://www.example.com/blah/blah<br>
www.example.com/<br>
www.example.com/blah/blah
</div>
<br>
<div id="links2"></div>
```

I would also like the https, http and www. removed from the link text aswell, for example:

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/">example.com/</a>
<a href="www.example.com/">example.com/</a>
```

Does anyone know how?

Comment: what is your expected result?\

Comment: @decpk convert all plain text urls to href and just output the domain as the link text

Comment: I've answerd your question. Please have a look and tell me is this what you want?

Comment: @decpk how can I do it with .replace()?

Comment: Basic www problem is the `://` doesn't exist after www as implied by your regex

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
/^.*?\.(.*)/
```

If you want the original link in the `href` attribute then you can use `${link}` or if you want the link with domain only then you can use `${group}`

```js
const links = [
  "https://www.example.com/",
  "https://www.example.com/blah/blah/",
  "http://www.example.com/",
  "http://www.example.com/blah/blah",
  "www.example.com/",
  "www.example.com/blah/blah",
];
const result = links.map((link) =>
  link.replace(/^.*?\.(.*)/, (...args) => {
    const [, group] = args;
    return ` <a href="${link}" target="_blank">${group}</a><br>`;
  })
);

console.table(result);
```

Comment: The urls of the www.example.com/ links are internal and take the original url domain

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: Check this out https://jsfiddle.net/wyfpat9h/ click on the last two links and check how the url is structured.